# problem when I add permission to my model

Tags: odoo

Add the security to grant permissions to my groups, but when updating odoo I do not see the module installed and when entering with other users the system does not show me anything

security.xml

```
<record id="grupo_administrador" model="res.groups">

    <field name="name">Administrador</field>

</record>

<record id="grupo_profesor" model="res.groups">

    <field name="name">Profesor</field>

</record>

<record id="grupo_instructor" model="res.groups">

    <field name="name">Instructor</field>

</record>
```

ir.model.access.csv

```
access_administrador_profesor,gimnasio.profesor,model_gimnasio_profesor,gimnasio.grupo_administrador,1,1,1,1

access_administrador_alumno,gimnasio.alumno,model_gimnasio_alumno,gimnasio.grupo_administrador,1,1,1,1

access_administrador_plan,gimnasio.plan,model_gimnasio_plan,gimnasio.grupo_administrador,1,1,1,1

access_administrador_reserva,gimnasio.reserva,model_gimnasio_reserva,gimnasio.grupo_administrador,1,1,1,1

access_administrador_clase,gimnasio.clase,model_gimnasio_clase,gimnasio.grupo_administrador,1,1,1,1

access_profesor_rutina,gimnasio.rutina,model_gimnasio_rutina,gimnasio.grupo_profesor,1,1,1,1

access_profesor_ejercicio,gimnasio.ejercicio,model_gimnasio_ejercicio,gimnasio.grupo_profesor,1,1,1,1

access_profesor_evaluacion,gimnasio.evaluacion,model_gimnasio_evaluacion,gimnasio.grupo_profesor,1,1,1,1

access_profesor_progreso,gimnasio.progreso,model_gimnasio_progreso,gimnasio.grupo_profesor,1,1,1,1

access_profesor_reserva,gimnasio.reserva,model_gimnasio_reserva,gimnasio.grupo_profesor,1,1,1,1

access_profesor_alumno,gimnasio.alumno,model_gimnasio_alumno,gimnasio.grupo_profesor,1,1,1,1

access_profesor_plan,gimnasio.plan,model_gimnasio_plan,gimnasio.grupo_profesor,1,1,0,0

access_instructor_reserva,gimnasio.reserva,model_gimnasio_reserva,gimnasio.grupo_instructor,1,1,0,0

access_instructor_clase,gimnasio.clase,model_gimnasio_clase,gimnasio.grupo_instructor,1,1,0,0
```

Comment: To bring security groups you need define in groups in xml file. Check this [link](https://www.odoo.yenthevg.com/creating-security-groups-odoo/) it show how to add security permissions in odoo. The issue might occur due to wrong definition of security group.

Comment: Do you miss to add 'security/ir.model.access.csv' and  'security/security.xml', in your manifest file ?

Comment: yes, add the two securities in manifest but I can not make it apply in my module for the reasons mentioned in the topic. When entering with another user created does not let me do anything, I see the blank screen and the administrator does not show me the module that installs

Comment: when I run the module I get the following in the terminal WARNING demo odoo.models: The model gym.professor has not _description, the above with all the tables

Comment: @AZCHILENO  make sure you define that model in your py file.

Comment: I also added them to py file. In the odoo settings only one user is created to give permissions or something else is done?